# Unexpected result from argv

Tags: c

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    switch (argc){
    case 2:
        printf("arg = %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    case 3:
        printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("argv[2] = %s\n", argv[2]);
        return 0;
    default:
        printf ("argc %d\n", argc); 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When giving the program an argument of 5* or 1* it gives unexpected results
otherwise normal.

```
$ argtst 5*     
argv[1] = 532
argv[2] = 532~

$ argtst 1*
arg = 1437

$ argtst 4*
arg = 4*

$ argtst "5*"
arg = 5*
```

Why?

(gcc version 4.2.1) 
(have tried with both ksh, sh, bash and csh)

Comment: Try `5\*` or `"5*"` instead of `5*`.

Comment: What Cool Guy said: The `*` is a metacharacter in many shells, an expression with a star is converted to a list of matching filenames. Type `echo 5*` to see how the arguments get expanded.

Comment: Solved my case had files with names 1437, 532, 532~, thanks.